# count with other fields in group by with hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, group-by, criteria

I want to return **count** of rows with some other fields in a group by with hibernate, and i have not any field in my entity class representing count. for example i have a Payment entity class:

```
class Payment
{
    private Long id;
    private String totalCode;
    private String activityCode;
    private Long amount;

    // other fields and setter/getters
}
```

sql query:

```
select count(*), sum(p.amount), p.total_code, p.activity_code 
from  tb_payment p
group by p.total_code,p.activity_code
```

and my hibernate criteria:

```
Session session = getCurrentSession();
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();        
projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("totalCode"))
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("activityCode"))
        .add(Projections.sum("amount"))
        .add(Projections.count("id"));
Criteria criteria  = session.createCriteria(Payment.class);
criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
List<Payment> payments = criteria.list();
```

As i said, my problem is i don't know where/how can i access the value of count (from criteria.list())!?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think here is the correct version of your code:

```
Session session = getCurrentSession();
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();        
projectionList.add(Projections.groupProperty("totalCode"))
        .add(Projections.groupProperty("activityCode"))
        .add(Projections.sum("amount"))
        .add(Projections.rowCount());
Criteria criteria  = session.createCriteria(Payment.class);
criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
List<Object[]> payments = criteria.list();
for (Object[] payment : payments) {
    System.out.println("totalCode: " + payment[0]);
    System.out.println("activityCode: " + payment[1]);
    System.out.println("amountSum: " + payment[2]);
    System.out.println("rowCount: " + payment[3]);
}
```

Comment: What is the way the same I can Achive using JPA 2 using entity manager and CriteriaQuery.. I am not able to find a way to use projection with CriteriaQuery.

Comment: Great answer. Saved ample time after fighting for long.