# hibernate Projections for spring boot application

Tags: java, json, postgresql, hibernate

i have a table which contains following fields

```
|id|feedback_status|financial_year|attendence|behaviour|total_feedback|user_id|total_behaviour|
```

Iam fetching feedback_status and total_feedback from that table and return as json data using hibernate with projections and projectionlist.

```
    List<StudentFeedback> results = null;

                Session session = getSession();
                Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(StudentFeedback.class);

                ProjectionList projlist = Projections.projectionList();
                projlist.add(Projections.property("totalFeedback").as("qty"));
                projlist.add(Projections.groupProperty("feedbackStatus").as("feedName"));

                criteria.setProjection(projlist);
                criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
                results = criteria.list();
}
    return GsonUtils.toGson(results);
    }
```

My feedback_status and total_feedback contains following values

```
|feedback_status|          |total_feedback |
    Excellent                   23
    Average                     11
    Poor                        12
    Good                        13
    Poor                        12
```

So the problem is whenever returning the json,it prints the `feedback_status` value **`poor`** two times and  i want only the values to be printed once and if it occurs more than once then sum the `total_feedback` corresponding to the `feedback_status`and returns to single one.

Comment: Hello Bro,
 Can you try to use .setProjection(Projections.countDistinct("feedback_status")); 
Eg : Criteria criteria = createCriteria(values).setProjection(Projections.countDistinct("feedback_status"));

Comment: @PradeepCG is this helpful for results to be printed as grand total_feedback??

Comment: hey you need to use sum in combination with count for restriction please check these links 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044565/count-with-other-fields-in-group-by-with-hibernate 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23044565/count-with-other-fields-in-group-by-with-hibernate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer by using `groupProperty`   in hibernate porjections

By the way Thanks Pradeep CG

```
List<StudentFeedback> results = null;

Session session = getSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(StudentFeedback.class);

ProjectionList projlist = Projections.projectionList();
projlist.add(Projections.sum("totalFeedback").as("qty"));
projlist.add(Projections.groupProperty("feedbackStatus").as("feedName"));


criteria.setProjection(projlist);
criteria.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);
results = criteria.list();

return GsonUtils.toGson(results);
```